# Null pointer exception due to calling a function in constructor and then creating a new object of that class

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

How to write j-unit for a class which calls a super function(non static) due to which a null pointer exception is happening.

```
public myActivity(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

        mContext = context;
        Window window=getWindow();
        window.dosomething();
}
```

Now when creating a spy object

```
Myactivity  activity = spy(new Myactivity (mContext));
```

Its throwing a null pointer error in `getWindow()`
where getWindow() is a function of Dialog.class

getwindow is android code

```
 public @Nullable Window getWindow() {
        return mWindow;
    }
```

I have to create the window in constructor .
Can you please help in removing the null pointer error

Comment: Could you add your getWindow() code here?

Comment: Hello I have added it